# ar_track_alvar on ARM Odroid-U3

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, odroid, ar-track-alvar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Has anyone installed ar_track_alvar on arm yet? I'm wanting to do this on an Odroid-U3 which is armv7l.

Is it available in Debian, or prebuilt binary? Or most likely I'll need to built from source.

I know it depends on pcl_ros, but I'm also wondering if you can build without this if not using kinect depth based features?

Any tips or previous work people has done on this would be much appreciated.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/164946/ar_track_alvar-on-arm-odroid-u3/) by [ggregory8](https://answers.ros.org/users/15261/ggregory8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-05-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ar_track_alvar isn't available as a prebuilt binary for Ubuntu on ARM, according to the [Hydro ARM status page](http://packages.namniart.com/hydro.html). I don't remember exactly why it wasn't building, but I think it was due to a bug in ar_track_alvar or one of its direct dependencies; it shouldn't be too hard to fix.

The good thing is that there are binary builds of most of the core packages such as PCL, so you won't have to spend time trying to build those yourself. You can install ROS and most of the dependencies you'll need by following the [ROS UbuntuARM Install Guide](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/UbuntuARM)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ggregory8](https://answers.ros.org/users/15261/ggregory8/) on 2014-05-14**:
Thanks for the reply. I found http://64.91.227.57/repos/rospbian/debbuild/groovy.html which is specific for Raspbian. I haven't quite figured out how those pages work but it looks like ar_track_alvar is available as a debian package from this farm.
Any ideas if this would likely run on Linaro 12.11, or is Raspbian quite different. Alternatively how do I find the source for these packages listed on this site?  I could use there source as a base as Raspberry Pi is ARM architecture too.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-05-14**:
Rasbian is armv6; binaries compiled for raspbian probably won't run on newer chips, and if they do, they probably won't run well. Most of the binary builds are all built from the upstream sources; I would just try checking out ar_track_alvar from the official sources.

**Comment by [ggregory8](https://answers.ros.org/users/15261/ggregory8/) on 2014-05-14**:
Ok I didn't realise it was armv6. I did actually checkout the offical ar_track_alvar package and try to compile, but was having alot of depenancy errors that were related to the pcl_ros packages etc. I haven't troubleshoot this yet so, I'll get back to that and see how I go. I just wanted to see if anyone had already done this.

I'll report back with any specific errors I encounter that I can't resolve for help. Thanks.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-05-14**:
You should be able to install most of the required dependencies from debs if you're using the Hydro builds for Ubuntu ARM. I would start with 'sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-pcl-ros'

**Comment by [ggregory8](https://answers.ros.org/users/15261/ggregory8/) on 2014-05-15**:
I didn't realise Hydro had alot more support for ARM debs. I was using Groovy. So I installed Hydro and managed to install all dependencies via apt-get. The ar_track_alvar compile from source seemed to go without any errors. Just ran out of time to test. I will update tomorrow.

**Comment by [ggregory8](https://answers.ros.org/users/15261/ggregory8/) on 2014-05-16**:
Yes this is working now. Thanks for the advice!